# pandas datframe replace numerical columns with condition on categorical columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have dataframe as :

```
    Final_Status    Delivered_cnt   RTO_cnt
1   RTO             0               1
2   RTO             4               1
3   Delivered       4               1
4   RTO             5               1
5   RTO             2               3
6   Delivered       1               1
```

based on Final_Status column value ,
I want to update  Delivered and RTO value .

For example:
first row Final_Status is RTO , RTO_cnt decrease by 1.so row1 becomes :

```
RTO             0           0
```

else if Final_Status is Delivered,Delivered_cnt decrease by 1.so row3 becomes  :

```
Delivered       3               1
```

Final table should be something like this :

```
    Final_Status    Delivered_cnt   RTO_cnt
1   RTO             0               0
2   RTO             4               0
3   Delivered       3               1
4   RTO             5               0
5   RTO             2               2
6   Delivered       0               1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked :

```
  df1['Delivered'] = df1['Delivered'].mask(df1.Final_Status == 'Delivered',  df1['Delivered']-1)
  df1['RTO'] = df1['RTO'].mask(df1.Final_Status == 'RTO',  df1['RTO']-1)
```